# SQL STUFF not working, why?

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions, listagg

I did lot of querys on Oracle, and now I'm working with SQL Server.
I saw the way of use similar function like listagg from oracle in sql server (stuff).

```
    Select
    sqd.id_question,
    STUFF((Select ',' + nm_departament from tb_departament where sqd.id_departament = id_departament for xml path('')),1,1,'') nm_departements
from
    tb_survey_question_departament sqd
```

The sintax its correct, but the result not.

[image: Notice the records related to id 1]

The goal is have for example for the 2 top rows, the result as 1 - RH, Planta Brasilia

Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `distinct id_question` first and `inner join` to `tb_departament`  like this

```
Select
    sqd.id_question,
    STUFF(( 
             SELECT ',' + td.nm_departament 
             from tb_departament td
             INNER JOIN tb_survey_question_departament  sqd1 ON sqd1.id_departament = td.id_departament 
             WHERE  sqd1.id_question = sqd.id_question
             FOR XML PATH('')
         )
         ,1,1,'') AS nm_departements
from
    (
       SELECT DISTINCT sqd.id_question 
       FROM tb_survey_question_departament sqd 
    ) sqd
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing group by id_Question...

```
Select
sqd.id_question,
STUFF((Select ',' + nm_departament from tb_departament where sqd.id_departament = id_departament for xml path('')),1,1,'') nm_departements
    from
tb_survey_question_departament sqd  
group by sqd.id_question
```

Comment: No, this will not work. This will just raise an error because of the group by (SQL will not be able to group the STUFF properly as a result). The issue is with the STUFF statement itself, because it's not joint to the outer query correctly, but without seeing sample data, it's hard to recommend how to fix this.

Comment: Yes, you're right if I put group the problem is:
Column 'tb_survey_question_departament.id_departament' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

The data has the problem that I show on the first two rows, that is a id_question has 1 or more id_departement associate, so I need to show only a row by id_question and aggregate the 'n' departements

Comment: @MCunha98 Your stuff should look something like this: `STUFF((SELECT ',' + d.nm_departament FROM tb_departament AS d JOIN tb_survey_question_departament AS sqd2 ON sqd2.id_departament = d.id_departament WHERE sqd2.id_question = sqd.id_question FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')`

Comment: You could try my answer @MCunha98

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE tblSample (
EMPNAME VARCHAR(10)
,DEPTNAME VARCHAR(10)
,LEAVETYPE VARCHAR(20)
,TOTALLEAVE INT
);
```

---

```
    INSERT INTO tblSample (EMPNAME, DEPTNAME, LEAVETYPE, TOTALLEAVE)
        VALUES ('ANDREW','CSE','SICKLEAVE',3)
            ,('GEORGE','IT','CASUALLEAVE',1)
            ,('ANDREW','CSE','CASUALLEAVE',2)
            ,('GEORGE','IT','SICKLEAVE',2);
```

---

```
SELECT EMPNAME
,DEPTNAME
,STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + LEAVETYPE + '-' + CAST(TOTALLEAVE AS VARCHAR(5))
        FROM tblSample
        WHERE EMPNAME = T.EMPNAME
            AND DEPTNAME = T.DEPTNAME
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, '') AS LEAVETYPE
,SUM(TOTALLEAVE) AS TOTALLEAVE
FROM tblSample T
GROUP BY EMPNAME
,DEPTNAME
-----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help guys, here the final sql works fine:

```
Select
    sqd.id_question,
    que.ds_question,
    STUFF(( 
             SELECT ',' + td.nm_departament 
             from tb_departament td
             INNER JOIN tb_survey_question_departament  sqd1 ON sqd1.id_departament = td.id_departament 
             WHERE  sqd1.id_question = sqd.id_question
             FOR XML PATH('')
         )
         ,1,1,'') AS nm_departements
from
    (
       SELECT DISTINCT sqd.id_question 
       FROM tb_survey_question_departament sqd 
    ) sqd
    inner join tb_survey_question que on sqd.id_question = que.id_question
```