# Conversion of MySQL queries to SQl Server queries in drupal application

Tags: mysql, sql-server, drupal-7, database-migration

I am migrating my database from MySQl to SQL Server. My app is built on top of drupal. I am not able to convert the following code to its SQL Server equivalent :
`addExpression("GROUP_CONCAT(qa.answer SEPARATOR ',') ", 'lookingfordetails')`.

What is the SQL Server equivalent of `GROUP_CONCAT()` and how do I implement it in `addExpression()`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server - note that it does depend on your version of SQL Server (it can be painful, but is always do-able).

Comment: you can use Stuff function. [Check the below post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server)

Comment: you can use Stuff function. [Check the below link for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146920/sql-stuff-not-working-why)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this works because I can't test it, but I suggest something like this:

```
$expression = 'STUFF((SELECT ',' + answer as lookingfordetails FROM table FOR XML PATH('')),1 ,1 ,'')';

$query->addExpression($expression);
```

I think you could see group_concat conversion to other databases:
http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/functions/group_concat

Comment: will test this out and confirm back.